# Bluetooth headset doesn't play ringtone

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-hsp

I've paired Bluetooth headset Plantronics Explorer 390 with Android phone. I can set ringtone of incoming call on every contact. The issue is that any Android phone I've tested plays ringtone on internal speaker. In headset I hear at this moment standard beep-beep-beep. Is any way to send ringtone to BT headset?

Of course, BT headset ideally works in other terms: when I answer the call, sound output is redirected to headset as I expect and phone is using mic in headset.

But on every Nokia phone ringtone is correctly redirected to BT. It is very disappointing that newer and more functional Android lacks this feature.

I've tested next phones:

- LG Optimus One P500
- HTC Inspire 4G

I've tested different versions of firmware. From 2.2 to 2.3.4. The behavior is identical.

Comment: The same behaviour appears on my Samsung SBH170 and Galaxy S. Can't remember ever, on any phone, hearing the ringtone through the headset though, it's always the built-in beeps.

Comment: On Nokia 6230i and Nokia 5310 ringtone is played through BT headset. So there are such phones. But they are based on different OS.